How do people apply mods to The Legend of Zelda: Breath of the Wild?
Breath of the Wild is a highly popular game. As such, many people have streamed it, made YouTube videos of it, etc. A lot of people have even modded it, to do challenge runs and the like (randomiser run, etc).
However, it is a Nintendo Switch game, and a Switch game only. It shouldn't be available anywhere else.
So how do people actually apply mods to it? If it's a Switch game, shouldn't it be therefore unmoddable?

"However, it is a Nintendo Switch game, and a Switch game only" — Actually, it's also available for the Wii U, which is a lot more moddable than the Switch.

There are many emulators online that BotW can be run on like CEMU which are easily moddable. You can dump game files from the Wii into the emulator and run it then easily install mods.

BotW may also be modded on an actual switch, provided it is running custom firmware. The modding process is considerably more involved than simply patching the ROM (though the process eventually achieves the same thing).
